# NodeJS: thrift vs thrift-http package - which one to use?

Tags: node.js, thrift

What is the difference between these two packages to use thrift on NodeJS:
- [thrift](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thrift)
- [thrift-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thrift-http)
At first glance it appears `thrift-http` would be needed to use `thrift` over `http` but I installed the `thrift` package and it does have a `createHttpConnection` method defined in it. Here is sample code I wrote:

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var myService = require('./gen-nodejs/MyService');
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;
// connect to proxy on 127.0.0.1:8888
var connection = thrift.createHttpConnection('127.0.0.1', 8888, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol,
  path: 'http://localhost:5331/myhandler',  
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// Create a client with the connection
var client = thrift.createHttpClient(myService, connection);
console.log('calling getTotalJobCount...');

client.getTotalJobCount(function(count)
{
    console.log('total job count = ' + count);
});
```

But when I run it I get this:

```
total job count = NULL
```

This is not as expected as the service returns an integer which cannot appear as `NULL` in the client callback. I can't find the link now, but yesterday I read somewhere that thrift only supports `TJSONProtocol` over `http`. Is that correct even now? And is that the reason why I am seeing a `NULL`? Also where can I see the source code for thrift in nodejs? [This](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs) is the first link that appears in Google when searching for "thrift nodejs" and it seems the code is completely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

**The [thrift](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thrift) package is the one provided by the [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org) project team.**

The other one is someone elses package, not related to the "official" sources in any way. After a quick check against the relevant commits, the version of the files seems to be 0.9.3 as well, which is the most recent official release. However, I can't say whether all these files are entirely original, or if they have been modified. You will have to verify that on your own (or just trust that guy).